# exception while filtering the jqgrid when row count in the grid is zero

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, filter

How to avoid getting a exception from jQgrid when the row count is zero and filters are applied. my code looks like this

```
function filterGrid(grid, siteId, buildingId, cityId, selectedType) {   
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd } if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm } today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

        if (cityId == -1) {
            grid.setGridParam({ search: false });
        }
        else {
            var filter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [{ field: "CityID", op: "eq", data: cityId}] };

            if (siteId >= 0)
                filter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [{ field: "CityID", op: "eq", data: cityId }, { field: "SiteID", op: "eq", data: siteId}] }; // , { field: "BuildingID", op: "eq", data: buildingId}

            if (buildingId >= 0)
                filter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [{ field: "CityID", op: "eq", data: cityId }, { field: "SiteID", op: "eq", data: siteId }, { field: "BuildingID", op: "eq", data: buildingId}] };

            if (selectedType == "Outstanding Books")
                filter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [{ field: "CityID", op: "eq", data: cityId }, { field: "SiteID", op: "eq", data: siteId }, { field: "BuildingID", op: "eq", data: buildingId }, { field: "IsReturnDateNull", op: 'eq', data: true }, { field: "DueDate", op: 'gt', data: today}] };

            //For filtering
            grid.setGridParam({ search: true, postData: { filters: JSON.stringify(filter)} });

            //For searching   
            //grid.setGridParam({ search: true, postData: { searchOper: "eq", searchField: "Status", searchString: selectedVal} });
        }

        grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
```

The Code that i have written works perfectly fine BUT if the datasource has no records to bind with the grid then i get an exception, I thought of getting the row count into a hidden field on the server side and on the client side if the row count is zero in the hidden field then skip searching, but since the datasource is getting assigned to the jqgrid during an asynchronous call back hence value in the hidden field is not getting updated(always get empty string in hiddenfield on client side) so can any body help me how to avoid getting a null exception from the jqgrid when there is no data bound to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this question. I used the event onsearching of the jqgrid and on the server side i get the row count from a hidden field that contains the current row and if the row count is 0 then i cancel the search operation.

```
protected void grdBookTransaction_Searching(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GridCount.Value) || GridCount.Value == "0")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```